# Cisco Show Privilege via SNMP

Tags: cisco, security, snmp

How to get Cisco privilege level via SNMP?

```
R1#show privilege
Current privilege level is 15
```

Which MIB or OID?

Comment: What privilege level would you expect there? SNMP doesn't have a privilege level, it's not a user.

Comment: @TeunVink I need just this `Current privilege level is 15` message via SNMP. e.g: OID request from SNMP server to Cisco device and Cisco response them. Which MIB or OID to send and get privilege level info of cisco?

Comment: As I said, SNMP is not a user, it does not have a privilege level in that way. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @TeunVink Oops! yes, SNMP is not a user. Thanks.

Comment: Let me make an answer out of this so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNMP is not a user, it does not have a privilege level in that way, so you're not able to retrieve this information.

Comment: Is it get all user privilege? Is there a MIB of user?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. You can try searching on the Cisco website.